# How do I use an elements' attribute value as a css property? CSS3

Tags: html, css, properties, attributes

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
</canvas>

<div class="content"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.content {
  :root {
    --xPos: canvas[id="canvas"].width/2;
}   
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--xPos);
  bottom: 100px;
}
```

I tried using an attribute selector to get the canvas.id.width value so I can set the left margin edge property for div.content to the canvas' width/2. 
However, it seems like attribute selectors are used to style elements with specific attributes/values rather than to return an attribute value.

is there a way(function/method) to use a HTML attribute value as a property value within CSS? and then use it in expressions like in JS such as attrValue*2 or attrValue/2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet widely supported in most browsers, see [attr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)

If its just a layout issue in different viewports, try to use [CSS calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) and/or [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

If its some behavior you want, try using JavaScript for that. With javascript, you could actually create the styles dynamically with whatever values you want, see [Set CSS styles with javascript](https://dev.to/karataev/set-css-styles-with-javascript-3nl5)